# cpu frequency impact on build graphic card

Tags: cpu, intel, frequency, decoder, energy

I'm working on building a Dynamic Voltage Frequency Scaling (DVFS) algorithm for a video decoding application operating on an [Intel core i7 6500U CPU (Skylake)](http://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz). The application is to support both software as well as hardware decoder modules and the software decoder is working as expected. It controls the operational frequency of the CPU which eventually controls the operational voltage, thereby reducing the overall energy consumption.

My question is regarding the hardware decoder which is available in the Intel skylake processor (Intel HD graphics 520) which performs the hardware decoding. The experimental results for the two decoders suggest that the energy consumption reduction is much less in the hardware decoder compared to the software decoder when using the DVFS algorithm.

Does the CPU frequency level adjusted on the software before passing the video frame to be decoded on the hardware decoder, actually have an impact on the energy consumption of the hardware decoder?.

Does the Intel HD graphics 520 GPU on the same chip as the CPU have any impact on the CPU's operational frequency and the voltage level?

Comment: Why did you need to implement your own DVFS in the first place?  Didn't Skylake's self-regulating mode work well?  (where you let the CPU's hardware power management controller make all the frequency decisions, instead of just choosing whether to turbo or not).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need to implement your own DVFS in the first place?  Didn't Skylake's self-regulating mode work well?  (where you let the CPU's hardware power management controller make all the frequency decisions, instead of just choosing whether to turbo or not).

Setting the CPU core clock speeds should have little to no effect on the GPU's DVFS.  It's in a separate domain, and not linked to any of the cores (which can each choose their clocks individually).  As you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)#Mobile_processors_.28See_also_.22Server.2C_Mobile.22_below.29), that SKL model can scale its GPU clocks from 300MHz to 1050MHz, and is probably doing so automatically if you're using an OS running Intel's normal graphics drivers.

For more about how Skylake power management works under the hood, see Efraim Rotem's (Lead Client Power Architect) IDF2015 talk (audio+slides, very good stuff).  The title is [Skylake Deep Dive: A New Architecture to Manage Power Performance and Energy Efficiency](http://myeventagenda.com/sessions/0B9F4191-1C29-408A-8B61-65D7520025A8/7/5#sessionID=155).

There's a link to the list of IDF2015 sessions in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guide. I'l go through these articles. I'm experimenting on energy consumption of the video decoders and customized application level solutions for energy management, such as DVFS. To clarify, what you've mentioned, does this mean that when we set CPU to operate at a very low frequency/voltage combination, the hardware decoder in Skylake chip could still operates at full capacity?. Is there no correlation between the two?. Is there a separate power management module for HD520 different from the CPU's?. Thanks

Comment: @userDtrm: Yes, AFAIK the GPU is in a totally separate voltage/frequency domain from the rest of the CPU.  Workloads with high GPU load but low CPU load are common, so Intel's designs certainly want to be able to take advantage of that.